# GreenDAO 3.1 queryBuilder when search property result is error

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements, greendao

I'm using greenDAO to save data from net, and I want to use the `dao.queryBuilder().where()` function to search the guid, but I can't get the correct result.

This is my DAO class :

```
public class NoteDao extends AbstractDao<SimpleNote, Long> {
    public static final String TABLENAME = "note";
    private static final String TAG = "NoteDao";

    public NoteDao(DaoConfig config, AbstractDaoSession daoSession) {
        super(config, daoSession);
    }

    public NoteDao(DaoConfig config) {
        super(config);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the underlying database table.
     */
    public static void createTable(Database db, boolean ifNotExists) {
        String constraint = ifNotExists ? "IF NOT EXISTS " : "";
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE note (\n" +
                "\t_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,\n" +
                "\tnid VARCHAR(100) ,\n" +
                "\ttitle VARCHAR(100),\n" +
                "\tguid VARCHAR(100),\n" +
                "\ttagNames VARCHAR(100),\n" +
                "\ttagGuids VARCHAR(100),\n" +
                "\tcontent VARCHAR(1000),\n" +
                "\tcreated Long,\n" +
                "\tupdated Long ,\n" +
                "\tdeleted Long,\n" +
                "\tstatus INTEGER default 0,\n" +
                "\tactive INTEGER DEFAULT 0,\n" +
                "\tnotebookGuid VARCHAR(50),\n" +
                "\tcontentHash VARCHAR(50) );"
        );
    }

    /**
     * Drops the underlying database table.
     */
    public static void dropTable(Database db, boolean ifExists) {
        String sql = "DROP TABLE " + (ifExists ? "IF EXISTS " : "") + "\"NOTE\"";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleNote readEntity(Cursor cursor, int offset) {
        SimpleNote entity = new SimpleNote();
        int guid = cursor.getColumnIndex("guid");
        String string = cursor.getString(guid);

        entity.setGuid(string);
        int title = cursor.getColumnIndex("title");
        String title1 = cursor.getString(title);
        entity.setTitle(title1);

        int content = cursor.getColumnIndex("content");
        String content1 = cursor.getString(content);
        entity.setContent(content1);


        int created = cursor.getColumnIndex("created");
        long created1 = cursor.getLong(created);
        entity.setCreated(created1);

        int updated = cursor.getColumnIndex("updated");
        long updated1 = cursor.getLong(updated);
        entity.setCreated(updated1);

        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long readKey(Cursor cursor, int offset) {
        return cursor.isNull(offset + 0) ? null : cursor.getLong(offset + 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void readEntity(Cursor cursor, SimpleNote entity, int offset) {
        entity = readEntity(cursor, offset);
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindValues(DatabaseStatement stmt, SimpleNote entity) {
        //stmt.bindLong(1, entity.get_id());
        if (entity.getTitle() != null && entity.getGuid() != null && entity.getCreated() != 0) {
            stmt.bindString(2, entity.getTitle());
            String content = entity.getContent();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(content)) {
                stmt.bindString(3, content);
            }

            stmt.bindLong(5, entity.getCreated());
            stmt.bindLong(6, entity.getUpdated());
            stmt.bindLong(7, entity.getDeleted());
            stmt.bindString(8, entity.getGuid());


        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Long updateKeyAfterInsert(SimpleNote entity, long rowId) {
        entity.set_id(rowId);
        return rowId;
    }


    @Override
    protected Long getKey(SimpleNote entity) {
        if (entity != null)
            return entity.get_id();
        else return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isEntityUpdateable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long insert(SimpleNote entity) {
        if (entity != null) {

            long count = queryBuilder().where(Properties.guid.eq(entity.getGuid())).count();
            if (count == 0) {
                super.insert(entity);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void delete(SimpleNote entity) {
        super.delete(entity);
    }

    public static class Properties {
        public final static Property Id = new Property(0, Long.class, "_id", true, "_id");

        public final static Property title = new Property(1, String.class, "title", false, "title");
        public final static Property content = new Property(2, String.class, "content", false, "content");
        public final static Property contentHash = new Property(3, String.class, "contentHash", false, "contentHash");
        public final static Property active = new Property(4, Integer.class, "active", false, "active");

        public final static Property createTime = new Property(5, Long.class, "created", false, "created");
        public final static Property updateTime = new Property(6, Long.class, "updated", false, "updated");
        public final static Property deleteTime = new Property(7, Long.class, "deleted", false, "deleted");


        public final static Property guid = new Property(8, String.class, "guid", false, "guid");

        public final static Property status = new Property(12, Integer.class, "status", false, "status");
        public final static Property nid = new Property(13, String.class, "nid", false, "nid");
    }


}
```

This is the search code:

`noteDao.queryBuilder().where(NoteDao.Properties.guid.isNull()).build();`

The result:

[image]